# Svg file not displaying properly

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I'm using  `flutter_svg: ^1.1.6`  package. The svg file I want to display is not showing properly.
I've also tried cleaning the svg but no luck.  Colors on the image looks completely washed out .I'll attach code and images for references.
Code :

```
SvgPicture.asset(
            ImageConstant.imgGroup1207,
           
          )
```

[image: original Image]
[image: Image displayed on app]

I've also tried cleaning the svg but no luck.

Comment: You may want to check the svg image in a web browser. Also, is it possible the widget is covered by another widget set to 50% opacity? If you post more of the code we can help you more.

Comment: on a stateless widget :  ``` 
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
body: Center (
child: Column(
children:[
SvgPicture.asset(
                  SvgAsset,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
]

)
),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a png image.
Then you can convert it into svg using express.adobe.com
There is an option called Convert to SVG.

I have also used other online tools to convert png to SVG,  but the quality was poor. From Adobe, you could get svg file close enough to a png file. There might still be minor missing patches.